# Searching for users and returning friends first (Order)

Tags: php, sql

I'm using the following query to select users from my 'users' table with the logged-in user's session id here being $uid:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, uid, hometown from users  where concat(first_name,' ',last_name) like '%$q%' and uid <> $uid LIMIT 6
```

I also use the following query to select all of the user's friends from the 'friends' table:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.uid, a.last_name FROM users a, friends b WHERE a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = $uid
```

My question is how would I order such a query with the friend's users at the top? So for example, if my user searches 'Dave' and I return 5 people with the first name, Dave, how can I rank his friend Dave on top of all the other Daves and order the query in such a manner?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the friends table, are there always two rows in the table per relationship? i.e. (5 -> 9), (9 -> 5) or is it just one row, with the uid being in either column?

Comment: I'm using a two row system, so (5->9),(9->5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name,
    a.uid,
    a.hometown,
    IF(b.friend_two IS NULL, 0, 1) AS isFriend
FROM
    users a
LEFT JOIN
    friends b ON a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = $uid
WHERE
    CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) LIKE '%q%'
    AND a.uid <> $uid
ORDER BY
    isFriend DESC
```

Comment: Indeed, and so is `CONCAT()` =)

Comment: Or leave out the `IF` entirely and use `b.friend_two IS NOT NULL AS isFriend`

Answer (score -2):

My best idea would be to set a 'rank' in your database and give them a value of 1 for the people who you want ordered first.

```
SELECT `fields` FROM `table` ORDER BY `rank` DESC
```